# Disable Preference based on Value of its Dependency (Code Check)

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences

I am attempting to do something I'm unsure of, and need someone to provide feedback.

I have 2 preferences. One of them, I want dependent on the other one's value.

Example: My "Notification Mode" Preference has 2 options: "Timer", and "Reminder"

If the User chooses the "Timer" option, I want my other Preference available to set time.

Otherwise, I want the Preference for setting the Timer to be disabled.

Here's what I've come up with inside my pref changed listener:

```
if (key.equals(PREF_NOTIFICATION_MODE)) {

    Preference notifModePref = findPreference(key);
    notifModePref.setSummary(sharedPreferences.getString(key, ""));

    if(!notifModePref.equals("Timer Mode")) {

        Preference timerDurationPref = findPreference(PREF_TIMER_DURATION);
        timerDurationPref.onDependencyChanged(notifModePref, true);

    } else if(notifModePref.equals("Timer Mode")) {

        Preference timerDurationPref = findPreference(PREF_TIMER_DURATION);
        timerDurationPref.onDependencyChanged(notifModePref, false);
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if I'm doing this correctly, or if `onDependencyChanged` is proper.

Comment: **UPDATE:** So far, I got the Timer Amount Preference to successfully "Disable" when it's Dependency get's changed to a value other than "Timer mode", but when I change it BACK to "Timer mode", the Timer Amount Preference stays Disabled..

Comment: Can you rephrase your question or requirement.

Your required code might be simpler than your question.


And can you paste the code under which you have written about code and preference xml file as well .

And one more thing to note , Why are you not using two keys for check instead of only one "Timer Mode"

Comment: @RahulPatil I **am** referencing two keys (hence the `if (key.equals(PREF_NOTIFICATION_MODE))` with another `if` to check if that `key` is equal to `"Timer Mode"` or not.. Anyhow, I simply wanted to know if I was using `onDependencyChanged` in the correct way, but I accomplished the Goal using `if` statements` and `isEnabled`, combined with `onDependencyChanged`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accomplished the Goal inside of `if(key.equals)` by referencing the `Preference` in question and using `if` statements and a combination of using `onDependencyChanged()`, and setting `.isEnabled(boolean)` as required.